# Close JIRA issue via git using bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, jira

I've recently intalled JIRA and bitbucket in my server to work with them. I connected both applications using the Attlasian tutorial by setting an application link in JIRA. I can see in the list that bitbucket is connected and the smart commits are activated.

I don't know if there is something missing or I don't know how to close the issues. I'm working over a project called Tango and there is the following issue:

tango / TAN-1

If I've understood properly, an issue can be closed by using this commit:

git commit -m "TAN-1 #resolve"

Nothing happens in my case.

Could anybody help me to understand how to manage the issues?

Comment: Are other smart commits working correctly?

Comment: What do you mean? @GeneTaylor

Comment: So feature that lets you close issues like that is called 'Smart Commits' and it lets you perform a couple of other actions like adding comments to issues or logging time [see Atlassian docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-smart-commits-in-bitbucket-server-802599018.htm).

I would check to see if you can get another type of smart commit to work so we can narrow down where the problem is.